# Should I list my work as dissertation or conference paper?

Tags: publications, cv

I have a dissertation under the supervision of my advisor. Then my university hosted a conference and we decided to make it a paper. The paper will soon publish on the conference's website, but it won't have peer-review. Should I list my work as a dissertation or a conference paper?

Comment: Are you talking bout the CV?  Because typically you have a education section where you list your institution, degree, year, and title of the disertation.  Then in another section you have conference presentations, and the paper could go there.

Comment: Yes, I ask the question under the tag [tag:cv]. So you suggest that my work can have both form: dissertation and paper, am I correct?

Comment: Yes they are independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a CV you try to organize your important personal information in a clear and useful way for others to see and gain a good perspective. In this case you have a thesis. It should clearly be listed so that it is clear it is one of the outcomes of your degree. It is commonplace for people to turn a thesis into papers but that usually involves rewriting the material substantially. Such papers will be listed under headings such as, for example, "Peer-reviewed articles", "Conference contributions", "Abstracts", etc. In your case you could add your article under a heading such as "Conference contributions", Non-reviewed articles" or "Other articles" (the later only makes sense if you have a heading "Peer-reviewed articles") and make sure it is clear that the heading also implies the articles are not peer reviewed.

If your article and your thesis is, in fact practically the same text with the same title, it would not be advisable to follow the guidelines outlined above. the reason is that it may seem to a reader of the CV as if you are trying to inflate your publication record. In that case you could perhaps make a note in the CV in conjunction with the thesis that it has also been published under the same name or to add it under a different heading but stating that the paper is the same as the thesis, thereby taking the possible edge of the double appearance.

In the end it is clearly not a problem to publish thesis material after a degree and still count both the thesis and the resulting article but the basic rule is that a specific text should not be counted twice. It would then essentially count as self-plagiarism. So just act responsibly and be open and honest about issues that can cause confusion or raise eye-brows.

Comment: Thank you so much. To clear my situation, I want to add that I'm just a graduate student, not PhD nor Ms. The article is a short version of my dissertation. The structure is change, the title is change, some part is cut off but basically there is no change in writing for the selected parts. Which solution is best for me?